# Using a Connection String or Variable from an Included PHP File

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

**Description :**

I have started using mysqli_* functions before that I was using mysql_* now the mysqli_* requires a variable lets say `$con` to be passed as a`enter code here`n argument to the mysqli_* function which contains this;

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

Now I have a different page at which I am connecting to the database which is just included at every php page to keep the work going like this;

--------- connect.php----------

```
<?php
if(!mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))
{
    echo "cannot connet to the server";
}
if(!mysql_select_db("katchup"))
{
    echo "Cannot connect to the database";
}
?>
```

and other pages like this

----------- get_products.php -----------

```
include 'connect.php';

$result = mysql_query("any query"); // this is what I have 

$result = mysqli_query($con , "any query"); // this is what I want
```

My question is how do I get the `$con` in connect.php in other pages?

Comment: you have to go with mysqli from the scratch dont use mysql the tag is deprecated now and php dont support it anymore

Comment: @AitazazKhan That's what he's trying to learn how to do.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 but we should give him reason why this was nt working

Comment: PHP deprecated mysql api you should use mysqli instead.
`$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");`
this is right way...
and if you are creating function for query you just need to call `global $con` inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this in your   connection file

```
<?php
//mysqli_connect("servername","mysql username","password",'database')
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","",'business');

if(!$con)
{
    echo "cannot connet to the server";
}

?>
```

And in your get product.php etc file use mysqli like this.

```
<?php
 include('connection.php');
 $query=mysqli_query($con,"your query");
//for single record
 if($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
 {
   your data will be here
 }
//for multiple records
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
//your data will be fetched here
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple.

In connect.php

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
if ($con->connect_errno) echo "Error - Failed to connect to database: " . $con->connect_error;
```

Then `$con` will be available in the php scripts you include connect.php in (after you include), and you can use this;

```
$result = mysqli_query($con , "any query");
```

or you can use OO instead if you want, like this;

```
$result = $con->query("any query");
```

To use the connection in functions, you can either pass as a variable, or make `$con` global inside the function using `global $con;`.